# Angularjs change language ui-grid options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using  angular ui-grid not ng-grid. how can I to change the language english to spanish of the grid options.

Answer (score 10):

The solution I found is to change the default language of the service i18nService on the controller or in a configuration file. as following:

**Set default language on the controller**

```
var app = angular.module('moduleName');
app.controller('testController', ['i18nService', function(i18nService){
    //es is the language prefix you want
    i18nService.setCurrentLang('es');
}]);
```

**Set default language in a configuration file**

```
var app = angular.module('moduleName');
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator('GridOptions',['$delegate', 'i18nService', function($delegate, i18nService){
        var gridOptions;
        gridOptions = angular.copy($delegate);
        gridOptions.initialize = function(options) {
            var initOptions;
            initOptions = $delegate.initialize(options);
            return initOptions;
        };
        //es is the language prefix you want
        i18nService.setCurrentLang('es');
        return gridOptions;
    }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the directive `ui-i18n` on a div that contains the grid, like so:

`<div ui-i18n="{{lang}}">`

Taken straight from: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/104_i18n

Comment: I tried your suggestion but does not change the header texts.